# how to use stringstream to convert a string to an int and to a double at the same time

Tags: c++, stringstream

How do I convert a string into an int and a double using stringstream?

the input is going to be four digits followed by a period followed by another four digits (####.####) and i need to extract the first four digits into an int and then the whole thing needs to be a double, but im not sure where to go from here

```
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << s;
    int num1; // needs to be int
    ss.str(s);
    ss >> num1;
    ss.clear();
    ss << s;
    double num2; // needs to be a double
    ss >> num2;
```

For example, let's say we have `1234.5678` in the input. After the reading happens, I want to have `1234` in `num1`, and `1234.5678` in `num2`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: If `num2` needs to be a `double`, why are you defining it to be an `int`?

Comment: [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i fixed it, I just made this code quickly so i could get help understanding how to solve a problem in my code

Comment: Off topic: `ss.str(s);` effectively repeats `ss << s;`.

Comment: So, let's say you have `1234.5678` in the input, and that you have `int x; double y;` variables. After the magic happens, what do you want to have in `x` and what do you want to have in `y`? I mean, exactly, what values of x and y?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl i want x=1234 and i want y=1234.5678

Comment: Great. Therefore you should ignore 'x' at first, instead read the whole into `double y;`, and then you should ceil() that y value so you obtain the integral part of it - you can use ceil() math function, or just write cast `int x = (int)y;`

Comment: That was a unclear question then.

Comment: @Jeg It is not acceptable to edit a question such that the existing answers are invalidated. Please roll back this edit and ask a new question if you want to get the other four digits as an int.

Answer (score 4):

Parsing this twice is not needed, assuming the number is only 4 digits and not huge, a double should be able to hold the integral part precisely and therefore you can just truncate it down to an int afterwards.

```
stringstream ss("1234.5678");
double foo;
ss >> foo;
int bar = static_cast<int>(foo);
```

Comment: Or skip `stringstream` altogether and use `std::stod`, as R Sahu suggested.

Comment: @FredLarson That would be a good solution but not an answer to the question "How do I convert a string into an int and a double using stringstream?"